# Scriptmanager RegisterStartupScript does not work on Callbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, callback

I am using a third party UI Library (devexpress) to implement some data grids. These grids work with Callbacks (not UpdatePanel partial Postbacks).

I am trying to use Scriptmanager RegisterStartupScript to execute some code on the client after the callback. This works great with partial postbacks but does not work with Callbacks.

Is there any way to queue client side code for execution inside the callback server side handler?

Thanks

Comment: can't you have a look at the source/fiddler to find out what callback it's calling and then override that callback?

Comment: If you read [my blog post](http://zsoltmiskolczi.blogspot.com/2011/01/aspnet-web-server-control-for-rendering.html), you will see how to register client scripts on partial and full page postbacks too. Morzel

Comment: I am talking about Callbacks, not Partial or Full page postbacks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way :)

Comment: The callback is called internally by the Third Party Control, there are ways that I can do it by extending it, overriding some call, etc...I was trying to avoid going down that path thinking that there would be something in ASP.NET that would allow me to do that out of the box...I guess I have no alternative

Comment: Were you using ClientScriptManager or ScriptManager? Difference for callbacks is big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up fixing this issue was to implement my own client side callback handler, and rewriting the functionality to run on the client as opposed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

May I know that: do you put the control in the Update Panel?
If yes, then you may try the code below in your client side, I used to be like this but after this the code below, the problem solved :

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id="forModalPopUp">
         var prm =  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

         prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
         prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

         function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {

         }
         function EndRequest(sender, args) {

         }

    </script>
```

For more information: http://oysterleelife.blogspot.com/2012/05/scripmanager-error-in-updatepanel.html

Hope it can help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: I am not using an update panel. I am using a third party control library with it's own implementation of callbacks. I repeat they are not the same as partial postbacks implemented by UpdatePanels

Comment: what is the third party software you use? and what kind of the function that the software have? thanks and sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using DevExpress controls, they explain [HERE](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B190724/registerstartupscript-within-a-dx-callback) that RegisterStartupScript does not work with their Callbacks. They explain there how to implement client side script with their Callbacks.

Besides what is suggeted there, since you're using their Data Grids, those grids have a Client side EndCallback event that can be used to implement client side script.